# Issues Deserializing JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to use newtonsoft.json to deserialize a json string returned from White Pages Pro api. Everything worked perfectly and deserialized flawlessly UNTIL i got to is_commercial. Everything past there is where I run into issues with. The errors I'm encountering are as follows:

> WhitePagesTool.jsonPersonComplex' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'WhitePagesTool.jsonPersonComplex' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

All Errors Thrown Below

> Also throws the same error for all the following:
> firstname, middlename, lastname, age_range, gender, street_line_1, street_line_2, city, postal_code, state_code, country_code, latitude, longitude, accuracy, and associated_people

This is my Deserialization Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WhitePagesTool
{
    class jsonPersonComplex
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string phone_number { get; set; }
        public bool is_valid { get; set; }
        public string line_type { get; set; }
        public string carrier { get; set; }
        public bool is_prepaid { get; set; }
        public bool is_commercial { get; set; }
        public List<BelongsTo> belongs_to { get; set; }


        public class BelongsTo
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string firstname { get; set; }
            public string middlename { get; set; }
            public string lastname { get; set; }
            public string age_range { get; set; }
            public string gender { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }

        }
        public class CurrentAddress
        {
            public string street_line_1 { get; set; }
            public object street_line_2 { get; set; }
            public string city { get; set; }
            public string postal_code { get; set; }
            public string state_code { get; set; }
            public string country_code { get; set; }
            public LatLong lat_long { get; set; }
        }

        public class LatLong
        {
            public double latitude { get; set; }
            public double longitude { get; set; }
            public string accuracy { get; set; }
        }

        public class AssociatedPeople
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string firstname { get; set; }
            public string middlename { get; set; }
            public string lastname { get; set; }
            public string relation { get; set; }
        }

    }

}
```

This is my Entire Form coding

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WhitePagesTool
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        #region UI events

        private void cmdDeserialize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            deserialiseJSON(txtInput.Text);
        }

        private void cmdClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtDebugOutput.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        #endregion

        #region json functions

        private void deserialiseJSON(string strJSON)
        {
            try
            {
                //var jPerson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(strJSON);                         
                var jPerson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonPersonComplex>(strJSON);

                //debugOutput("Here's Our JSON Object: " + jPerson.ToString());

                debugOutput("Phone ID: " + jPerson.id.ToString());
                debugOutput("Phone Number: " + jPerson.phone_number.ToString());
                debugOutput("Valid Number: " + jPerson.is_valid);
                debugOutput("Line Type: " + jPerson.line_type);
                debugOutput("Carrier: " + jPerson.carrier);
                debugOutput("Prepaid: " + jPerson.is_prepaid);
                debugOutput("Commercial: " + jPerson.is_commercial);

                debugOutput("Name:  " + jPerson.Name);
                debugOutput("First Name:  " + jPerson.firstname);
                debugOutput("Middle Name:  " + jPerson.middlename);
                debugOutput("Last Name:  " + jPerson.lastname);
                debugOutput("Age Range:  " + jPerson.age_range);
                debugOutput("Gender:  " + jPerson.gender);

                debugOutput("Address:  " + jPerson.street_line_1);
                debugOutput("Extended Address:  " + jPerson.street_line_2);
                debugOutput("City:  " + jPerson.city);
                debugOutput("Postal Code:  " + jPerson.postal_code);
                debugOutput("State:  " + jPerson.state_code);
                debugOutput("Country:  " + jPerson.country_code);
                debugOutput("Latitude:  " + jPerson.latitude);
                debugOutput("Longitude:  " + jPerson.longitude);
                debugOutput("Accuracy:  " + jPerson.accuracy);

                debugOutput("Associate Name:  " + jPerson.associated_people.name);
                debugOutput("Associate First Name:  " + jPerson.associated_people.firstname);
                debugOutput("Associate Middle Name:  " + jPerson.associated_people.middlename);
                debugOutput("Associate Last Name:  " + jPerson.associated_people.lastname);
                debugOutput("Associate Relationship:  " + jPerson.associated_people.relationship);

                debugOutput("Associate Name:  " + jPerson.associated_people.name);
                debugOutput("Associate First Name:  " + jPerson.associated_people.firstname);
                debugOutput("Associate Middle Name:  " + jPerson.associated_people.middlename);
                debugOutput("Associate Last Name:  " + jPerson.associated_people.lastname);
                debugOutput("Associate Relationship:  " + jPerson.associated_people.relationship);


                debugOutput("Associate Name:  " + jPerson.associated_people.name);
                debugOutput("Associate First Name:  " + jPerson.associated_people.firstname);
                debugOutput("Associate Middle Name:  " + jPerson.associated_people.middlename);
                debugOutput("Associate Last Name:  " + jPerson.associated_people.lastname);
                debugOutput("Associate Relationship:  " + jPerson.associated_people.relationship);


                debugOutput("Associate Name:  " + jPerson.associated_people.name);
                debugOutput("Associate First Name:  " + jPerson.associated_people.firstname);
                debugOutput("Associate Middle Name:  " + jPerson.associated_people.middlename);
                debugOutput("Associate Last Name:  " + jPerson.associated_people.lastname);
                debugOutput("Associate Relationship:  " + jPerson.associated_people.relationship);


                debugOutput("Associate Name:  " + jPerson.associated_people.name);
                debugOutput("Associate First Name:  " + jPerson.associated_people.firstname);
                debugOutput("Associate Middle Name:  " + jPerson.associated_people.middlename);
                debugOutput("Associate Last Name:  " + jPerson.associated_people.lastname);
                debugOutput("Associate Relationship:  " + jPerson.associated_people.relationship);


            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                debugOutput("We Had A Problem: " + ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }



        #endregion

        #region Debug Output

        private void debugOutput(string strDebugText)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(strDebugText + Environment.NewLine);
                txtDebugOutput.Text = txtDebugOutput.Text + strDebugText + Environment.NewLine;
                txtDebugOutput.SelectionStart = txtDebugOutput.TextLength;
                txtDebugOutput.ScrollToCaret();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.Message.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

And this is the typical JSON String I'll be working with

```
{
  "id": "Phone.ID.Number",
  "phone_number": "5555555555",
  "is_valid": true,
  "country_calling_code": "1",
  "line_type": "Landline",
  "carrier": "Suddenlink Communications",
  "is_prepaid": false,
  "is_commercial": false,
  "belongs_to": [
    {
      "id": "Person.ID.Number",
      "name": "John Json Doe",
      "firstname": "John",
      "middlename": "Json",
      "lastname": "Doe",
      "age_range": "30+",
      "gender": "Male",
      "type": "Person",
      "link_to_phone_start_date": "2018-01-01"
    }
  ],
  "current_addresses": [
    {
      "id": "Location.ID.Number",
      "location_type": "Address",
      "street_line_1": "123 Annoying Street",
      "street_line_2": null,
      "city": "CSharp",
      "postal_code": "12345",
      "zip4": "1234",
      "state_code": "FL",
      "country_code": "US",
      "lat_long": {
        "latitude": 12.345678,
        "longitude": -12.345678,
        "accuracy": "RoofTop"
      },
      "is_active": true,
      "delivery_point": "SingleUnit",
      "link_to_person_start_date": "2018-01-01"
    }
  ],
  "historical_addresses": [

  ],
  "associated_people": [
    {
      "id": "Person.ID.Number",
      "name": "Jane Doe",
      "firstname": "Jane",
      "middlename": null,
      "lastname": "Doe",
      "relation": "Household"
    },
    {
      "id": "Person.ID.Number",
      "name": "John J Doe",
      "firstname": "John",
      "middlename": "J",
      "lastname": "Doe",
      "relation": "Household"
    },
    {
      "id": "Person.ID.Number",
      "name": "John Json Doe",
      "firstname": "John",
      "middlename": "Json",
      "lastname": "Doe",
      "relation": "PotentialOwner"
    },
    {
      "id": "Person.ID.Number",
      "name": "Jane J Doe",
      "firstname": "Jane",
      "middlename": "J",
      "lastname": "Doe",
      "relation": "PotentialOwner"
    },
    {
      "id": "Person.ID.Number",
      "name": "Jane Json Doe",
      "firstname": "Jane",
      "middlename": "Json",
      "lastname": "Doe",
      "relation": "PotentialOwner"
    }
  ],
  "alternate_phones": [

  ],
  "error": null,
  "warnings": [

  ]
}
```

Comment: `jsonPersonComplex` *doesnt* have a name property.  All those name props are in the `BelongsTo` class.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Perhaps your question can be a little more detailed. Now its too general.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour. Valid SO question. End of reviewing (triage). Enjoy SO ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You 'name' property isn't in the 'jsonPersonComplex' class but in the 'BelongsTo' class.

```
debugOutput("Name:  " + jPerson.name);  //should be
debugOutput("Name:  " + jPerson.belongs_to().FirstOrDefault()?.name); //sorta like this for example.
```

Also your naming convention is off.  Newtonsoft will automatically uppercase the names for you, although the lowercase should work I suggest making the c# version with c# standards.  Newtonsoft will convert following standards so it's ok.

I tried this and it works

```
namespace WhitePagesTool
{
    class JsonPersonComplex
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Phone_number { get; set; }
        public bool Is_valid { get; set; }
        public string Line_type { get; set; }
        public string Carrier { get; set; }
        public bool Is_prepaid { get; set; }
        public bool Is_commercial { get; set; }
        public List<BelongsTo> Belongs_to { get; set; }

        //Current_addresses added to address comments below.
        public List<CurrentAddress> Current_addresses { get; set; }
    }

    public class BelongsTo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Middlename { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string Age_range { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

    }

    public class CurrentAddress
    {
        public string Street_line_1 { get; set; }
        public object Street_line_2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Postal_code { get; set; }
        public string State_code { get; set; }
        public string Country_code { get; set; }
        public LatLong Lat_long { get; set; }
    }

    public class LatLong
    {
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
        public string Accuracy { get; set; }
    }

    public class AssociatedPeople
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Middlename { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public string Relation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And then in the logic...

```
var jPerson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonPersonComplex>(jsonString);  

debugOutput("Phone ID: " + jPerson.Id.ToString());
debugOutput("Phone Number: " + jPerson.Phone_number.ToString());
debugOutput("Valid Number: " + jPerson.Is_valid);
debugOutput("Line Type: " + jPerson.Line_type);
debugOutput("Carrier: " + jPerson.Carrier);
debugOutput("Prepaid: " + jPerson.Is_prepaid);
debugOutput("Commercial: " + jPerson.Is_commercial);

debugOutput("Name:  " + jPerson.Belongs_to.FirstOrDefault().Name); //and so on

//Street_line_1 added to address comments below
debugOutput("Name:  " + jPerson.Belongs_to.FirstOrDefault().Street_line_1); //and so on
```

Comment: Thanks a billion! I knew I should have never stopped coding years ago and continued with different languages. Everything is SO different then Visual Basic 6.0 was back when I coded more years ago then I can count. Again thank, that worked like a charm, and helped me figure out another issue I was having in a later build!

Comment: This is working flawless...However, ANY attempt to deserialize ANYTHING from the CurrentAddress class throws an error and hangs the deserialization sayin "We Had A Problem: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source" It starts with Street_line_1 although that value is NOT null. Nothing in that area is null. Any other area that returns a null value doesn't hang either, it simply leaves it blank.

Comment: @KhaosBringer How are you trying to print CurrentAddresses because remember CurrentAddresses is also an array within the Json.  This means you'll have to look within the array like I have done with linq for the Belongs_to.  First you'll need to add CurrentAddresses to the original JsonPersonComplexClass... ```public List<CurrentAddress> Current_addresses { get; set; }```  Then you'll have to write it in bebug like you do with Belongs_to ```debugOutput("Name:  " + jPerson.Belongs_to.FirstOrDefault().Street_line_1);  //and so on```

Comment: @KhaosBringer Please review my comment above this one and note that I have updated the answer to include Current_address for you with comments.  You'll need to follow this routine to complete the code for other objects.  I simply answered with the bare minimum to save space and you adding the rest will be good practice and help you understand.  If you need more help I'll gladly assist.